# !threads command showing XXX thread id

Tags: windbg, sos

When I run the !threads command, in the left most columns for few threads i see id as XXX. My understanding is that this mean dead threads. Does this includes any threads that exited (gracefully or ungracefully) or is it for any threads that didn't exit gracefully and were killed via APIs like Abort or Interrupt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, threads marked as XXXX are dead threads - i.e. they are no longer exist from the prospective of OS. CLR keeps information about threads a bit longer than OS, that is why you see dead threads in output.

Yes, both normally terminated and forcibly killed threads appear with XXXX in output.